# How to use the context properly in Golang Google Datastore package?

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore

I've started using Google Cloud Datastore in one of the project in the company I currently work in.

https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore

In the provided example, they use a context and pass it to the connection instance

```
ctx := context.Background()
dsClient, err := datastore.NewClient(ctx, "my-project")
```

Through the documentation you will see that they pass a context to all the functions that makes operations on the database, I am not sure if they are passing the same pointer or create a new pointer for each operation.

The current setup that I have is a global variable for the context in a package called "store" which I keep all the structs functions that communicate with the db, and I use that global variable each time. I don't know what is the effect of that, I am not sure why the context is used, Should I get reference of `context.Background()` each time I make operations on the database ?

Comment: Do not use a global context, that's not what it's meant for. Contexts are *request-scoped*. Each [request](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Context) carries it's own context and these contexts should not be shared between requests. If you have a single, global context and two concurrent requests use that context, there is a high probability of a data race.

Comment: @mkopriva contexts are already mutex-protected, and the package is naturally not really susceptible to races anyway, simply because of how it functions.  A context is a reverse linked list, ultimately pointing to the Background/TODO emptyCtx globals in the package.  Whenever you do something with a context, you're actually creating a child that points back to that parent context, not modifying the parent context itself.  The only "race" happen if you cancel the context, and that's not actually a race.  Contexts are designed to be able to be canceled by other goroutines.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that global contexts are questionable, but I've used a similar style before, where we had a global program-scoped context, which was then forked into a session-scoped context for each user session, and that was further forked into a call-scoped context for each RPC call the user made.  Contexts are scoped bags of stuff.  That scope doesn't always have to be a single request, and it's a perfectly valid use to have broader scopes for them.

Comment: Fair enough @Kaedys, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

context.Background is the global context--so no need for you global variable. Most of the time you'll want to use a child of that context, with a cancel or a timeout.

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background)
//or
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background, time.Second * 30)
```

Then you can use the cancel function to close down your application nicely, or cancel and retry if a request is hanging. If you never plan on canceling or timing out operations, then using context.Background is fine.

Also context.Context is an interface so it's always passed by reference, so all uses of a certain instance point to the same context.